# App failing to work after deployment via Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku in which I believe is working. Whilst testing my app via localhost it works fine, everything is posting. However after deployment and replacing all my URLs to Heroku, number of things are not working:

1. The GIPHY API no longer works
2. Nothing would post (comments and likes work but not the posting)

I have tried debugging however nothing has worked. Where am I going wrong? Please see below for details

app: https://mitnickproject1-journal-app.netlify.app/
heroku: https://journal-post-pl.herokuapp.com/print

Front-end code

```
const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
formEl.addEventListener('submit', postFormData)
let count=0;

async function postFormData(e) {
  const current= new Date().toLocaleString() 
  const formData= new FormData(formEl) // console.log this to check what format this is in 
  const formDataSerialised=Object.fromEntries(formData) //console.log this to see what this does
  const jsonObject = {...formDataSerialised, "dateTime": current, "comment": [], "EmojiCount": [0,0,0], "gifLink":gifLink, 'id': count}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2))
  try{
    const options = { method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  await fetch("https://journal-post-pl.herokuapp.com/test", options);
    // const response = await fetch("https://journal-post-pl.herokuapp.com/test", {

    // })
    // const json = await response.json();
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
    alert('There was an error')
  }
}
```

Back End Code

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    formData.push(req.body)
    console.log(formData)
    writeToJson();
    res.json({success: true})
})
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: After you post did you check your console, what debugging have you tried? Check browser network tab... mostly it should be a CORS issue.

Comment: I agree this could be a CORS issue. Another thing that comes to mind is if your environment variables are correct on Heroku

Comment: It just logs an error. I tried to do const options and then it just logs an error within the console @RhettHarrison I tried to do const options and throw the method: POST code on there but that doesn't work either. Not sure what to try next. It works on localhost but not when I add heroku links on there

Comment: It just logs an error. I tried to do const options and then it just logs an error within the console @Soheb I tried to do const options and throw the method: POST code on there but that doesn't work either. Not sure what to try next. It works on localhost but not when I add heroku links on there

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your code and tested it out while looking at the console.

1. Your GIPHY urls are using `http` instead of `https`. http is fine for development, but live site needs to use https. Just switch all your http urls to `https` and that will work.
2. Your server isn't set up to accept any requests from an outside source (AKA CORS). To fix this, just add `app.use(cors())` to your server file.
   Don't forget to put `const cors = require('cors')` at the top.

Comment: The GIPHY issue worked! I've added the cors code on there however it still does not post. It works on localhost but not on heroku